# Как повторно создать URL через createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, url, видео, blob, mediastream

Есть данный код:

```
function getVideoFromServer() {
    socket.on('video', video => {
        let blob = new Blob([video.video], {
            type: 'video/webm; codecs=\"vp8, opus\"'
        });

        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        videoTag.src = url;
    });
}
```

Первый раз URL создаётся и декодируется нормально, но второй раз выдаёт предупреждение: "Не удаётся декодировать медиаресурс"

Answer (score 1):

Потому что при создании [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) выделяется сегмент памяти для созданного объекта, эту память для каждого такого объекта нужно высвобождать, делается это при помощи [URL.revokeObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL).

Я бы сделал такую фабрику:

```js
const createVideoFromServerGetter = () => {
  let url;

  return () => {
    if (url) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }

    socket.on('video', video => {
      let blob = new Blob([video.video], {
        type: 'video/webm; codecs=\"vp8, opus\"'
      });

      url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      videoTag.src = url;
    });
  };
};

const getVideoFromServer = createVideoFromServerGetter();
```

Comment: Я дописал 

let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
videoTag.src = url;
URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);

Что-то не помогло

Comment: Прочтите внимательно документацию по `URL.revokeObjectURL`, которая прилинкована в ответе, данный метод принимает на вход созданный объект, чтобы очистить его из памяти, а не базовый блоб.

Comment: let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  videoTag.src = url;
  videoTag.onload = function() {
   URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  };

Дописал это, не помогло

Comment: Всё ещё читайте документацию, там написано: **Call this method when you've finished using an object URL to let the browser know not to keep the reference to the file any longer.**, это значит, что вы должны очищать предыдущий объект при повторном использовании функции в вашем случае. Соответственно нужно либо использовать внешнюю переменную (но лучше не надо), либо сделайте замыкание с фабрикой для функции `getVideoFromServer `.

Comment: Может просто дописать ивент onended для видео?

Comment: Поменял ивент на onended, не помогло

Comment: Как вам удобнее.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116031/discussion-between---and--kit).

Comment: Поменял, не помогло

Comment: Ок, хорошо.....

Comment: Ошибка кстати в самом вопросе, не удаётся декодировать

Comment: Обновил ответ, может поможет вам.

Comment: Всё также, не помогло, всё ещё не может декодировать

Comment: Только первый раз декодирует нормально, остальные не может, и так до обновления страницы

Comment: Можно как-то из Blob создать MediaStream? Просто это может решить проблему...

Comment: Это уже достаточно геморройный процесс, методом проб и ошибок только, что-то подобное обсуждается тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402263/how-to-send-getusermedia-recorded-stream-to-server-nodejs-realtime/45402485#45402485

Comment: Окей, можно хотя бы узнать как примерно можно Blob в MediaStream превратить

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API вот все возможности медиа стримов